# What is the best stack-exchange to ask about naming objects in code?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best stack-exchange to ask about the **naming** of fields, columns, classes, functions etc. in software?

Answer (score 6):

These kind of coding conventions are almost always **opinion based**, and I'm afraid none of the SE programming related sites would be a good fit to ask that.

Comment: I now realise, that I do not mean coding conventions, but actual naming of things.

Comment: @NickN. What's the difference? Did you mean _terminology_ of particular design patterns or programming language specific idioms?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [there](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) [are](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) [multiple](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming) [languages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [with](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) naming convensions mentioned by important parties. Those linked are just a few of those I bothered finding. Naming conventions are rarely opinion based as a result of multiple languages defining clear conventions

Comment: @Zoe It doesn't matter much _which_ convention is used. The point is that these should be used ***consistently*** throughout a project or company.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean naming as in CarService vs CarManager etc.

Comment: @NickN. Name these clearly about what's their purpose and responsibility. What does a `CarService` do? What does a `CarManager`do? Sounds like the latter is just a supplement for a fully fledged `CarService`. Follow natural language at best. There are no common rules.

Comment: Off course, I understand,, my question is if there is a stackechange suited for these kind of questions (I have a more complex question) maybe I should even just ask it in English.stackexchange.com